# What does "update current target for ipad" actually do?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

It doesn't seem to do much... :/

I don't have any (apart from MainWindow) XIB files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade Current Target for iPad does several things:

- sets the Targeted Device Family build setting to iPhone/Pad
- Base SDK of your project is also typically changed to iPhone Device 3.2 if that is not already the case
- creates a new main nib file to support iPad
- application’s Info.plist is updated to support the loading of the new main nib file when running on the iPad

This information is contained in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html), which goes into greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the WWDC 2010 video for Session 111 - iPad Development Overview.  There is a video walkthrough of the process.

(sorry don't have the link but you can access them via iTunes from your ADC account page)

Answer (score 0):

It won't appear to do much without any .xib files.  If you look in your Targets, however, you should now have 2.  That's the most important part.  After updating, you need to adjust your app to run on the iPad, which from what you posted you need to do programmatically.  Take a look at [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html) on updating to an iPad app.